# Types annotations for classes with dynamic attribute names

Tags: python

I have a class that uses its attributes as a dictionary. Like this:

```py
class Foo:

  def set(self, name: str, value: int):
    setattr(self, name, value)

  def get(self, name: str) -> Optional[int]:
    return getattr(self, name, None)
```

Is there any way to write down a type annotation to indicate that all member variables are `int` (if present)? Ideally in a way that Pyright understands.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax appears to partially work:

```
class Foo:
  __dict__: dict[str, int]

  def set(self, name: str, value: int):
    setattr(self, name, value)

  def get(self, name: str) -> Optional[int]:
    return getattr(self, name, None)
```

It is valid syntax, and it does mean Pyright treats `self.__dict__` as the correct type. Unfortunately it's not quite smart enough to change the return type of `getattr()` which still returns `Any`, but it's better than nothing!